# MYSQL:: Connector/Python UPDATE statement with special chars doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, mysql-connector

I'm trying to crawl web pages using Selenium and Beautifulsoup then store the results to MySQL.
The result contains many special chars like ; ' " =.. (since it is parsing HTML)

I followed this [mysql connector/python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-tutorial-cursorbuffered.html) and INSERT works fine, but UPDATE.
If I select my table I can see something like this

```
<div style="width:80px; float: ~~~ ... </div>
```

which means target HTML element is stored successfully. 
This is my INSERT and UPDTE.

```
# after import and configs
soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, "html.parser")
text = soup.prettify()
print(text)

# this INSERT works fine
# insert = ("INSERT INTO g_cache (a_col, cache_contents) VALUES(%s, %s)")
# data_row = ('aaa', text)
# cursor.execute(insert, data_row)

# Trying to UPDATE already inserted row. Not working
# I executed and commented above INSERT before run the following UPDATE
update = ("""UPDATE g_cache SET cache_contents =%s WHERE id=21""")
data_col = (text)
cursor.execute(update, data_col)

# If I use one complete string, it works though. For example
# cursor.execute("""UPDATE g_cache SET cache_contents ='111' WHERE id=21""")
cnx.commit()
```

Error message is
*mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE id=21' at line 1*

I just followed MYSQL:: Connector/Python API.
I don't understand why INSERT works but UPDATE doesn't, using the same string.
Anyone has any idea??

Comment: try `data_col = (text,)`. Afaik, the parameters must be passed as a tuple, the trailing comma after your variable is important here.

Comment: Oh it works with the comma thanks!! you should write it as an answer, so I can select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters must be passed as a mapping (i.e. dict) or as a tuple. Omitting the trailing comma when passing just one parameter causes it to be treated as a scalar, therefore the parameter must be passed like so:

```
data_col = (text,)
```

[The docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) also mention that in a prominent note.